# What math symbol can be used to express the same asymptotic order beside the big-Theta?

Tags: asymptotics

Suppose $a_n = O(b_n)$ and also $b_n = O(a_n)$.

I want to express this but can't use $\Theta$ since it means something else in my report.
I'm thinking about this $\approx$, but wondering if there is a better one.

I remember seeing a symbol like the $x$ rotated $90^0$, but don't know how it is called or the latex character.

Anyway, just want to hear your input.

Thank you!

Comment: I like $\asymp$

Comment: I like ~ , less strict looking than $\approx$

Comment: @mathematician this is usually used for asymptotic equality, that is the quotient is $1$ in the limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard symbol for this is $\asymp$, as you said. To typeset it use  `$\asymp$`.

If you know a symbol but not the command, use ["Detexify"](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), where you can draw symbols and are told the command.

Comment: So glad you showed me the Detexify! There are many symbols that I have no idea how they are called.

Comment: I am glad you found it useful. I think there is or at least used to be an add for it on this site.